# How to deploy application with Java 7 into CloudBees run@cloud with Maven

Tags: cloudbees

I know that it's possible to give the Java version with runtime parameter "-Rjava_version" when using the Bees SDK. Is it possible to give that runtime parameter when using Maven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time you have to set that up via the bees SDK (or api, or via a clickstart that launched it). However, once it is set - you don't need to set it each time (you only need to set parameters once, when the app is created in cloudbees).

Ie once you have called app:create (or anything, really) with -Rjava_version.... then you don't need to again (it will be preserved).

```
bees app:deploy -Rjava_version=1.7  -a account/appname
```

You can also use bees config:set to set -Rjava_version as well (only needs to be set once).

Comment: I noticed there is "config:set" which I can use to set the runtime config parameters I need. So, I can first set the parameters and then deploy with Maven.

Comment: To be explicit: bees config:set -Rjava_version=1.7 -a account/appname